# How to use escape characters in XML

Tags: android, xml

How can I use escape characters in XML?

The situation is, I am a new android developer, and I need a string which need to be printed in 2 lines (other wise no space). This string is in **string.xml** file. I need to use **/n** line break character to break the string, but I don't know how to do it in XML file. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See reference http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#String

line break symbol is \n

/n - is wrong.
and you can write it in xml like it is.

Example:

```
    <string name="multiline_text">line 1.\nline2.</string>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Android development but have you checked out CDATA?  Refer to [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp).

Basically, you wrap your string value like so:

```
<![CDATA[string value]]>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use double quotes:

```
<string name="mystring">"One line\nAnother line"</string>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the character entity `&#xA;` to indicate a linefeed.